# Appears this error for a list: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, iqr

I'm making a function to get the IQR of a list of columns.
But it returns me the following error:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The strange is that when I want to get the IQR of the first column of the list it works perfectly, but when I try other index in the list of columns it doesn't work.
I have tried the methods bool(), all(), any(), item() and empty but it doesn't works in a list.
Here's the code I have wrotten (All of the data doesn't exist, they are fictional characters):

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
ohe_encoder = OneHotEncoder()

diccionario_datos = {'Nombre': ['Eduardo', 'Ana', 'Alejandro', 'Álvaro', 'Aitana', 'María', 'Sofía', 'Antonio', 'Fernando', 'Laura'], 
                     'Grupo Sanguíneo': ['B+', '0+', 'AB+', '0+', 'A+', 'A+', 'B-', 'A+', 'AB+', '0+'], 
                     'Edad': [40, 35, 37, 24, 48, 53, 67, 25, 38, 21],
                     'Peso': [70, 69, 74, 70, 72, 67, 65, 74, 75, 70], 
                     'Ritmo Cardíaco': [70, 60, 68, 50, 68, 87, 110, None, 77, 69], 
                     'Presión sistólica': [129, 133, 125, 110, None, 130, 155, 126, 131, 127], 
                     'Presión diastólica': [None, 86, 82, 70, 82, 84, 100, 89, 90, 87]}
datos = pd.DataFrame(diccionario_datos)

ohe_gruposanguineo = pd.DataFrame(ohe_encoder.fit_transform(datos[['Grupo Sanguíneo']]).toarray())
datos = datos.drop('Grupo Sanguíneo', axis=1)
datos = pd.concat([datos, ohe_gruposanguineo], axis=1)

quartiles = [datos['Edad'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]), 
             datos['Peso'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]), 
             datos['Ritmo Cardíaco'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]), 
             datos['Presión sistólica'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]), 
             datos['Presión diastólica'].quantile([0.25, 0.75])]

def IQR (datos, columna):
  for caracteristica in quartiles:
    if (columna - 1) == quartiles.index(caracteristica):
      return(caracteristica[0.75] - caracteristica[0.25])
    elif columna - 1 > len(quartiles) or columna - 1 <= -1:
      return('Error: índice no contemplado en la longitud de la lista')
    else:
      continue

IQR(quartiles, 2)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: The error comes from this line `if (columna - 1) == quartiles.index(caracteristica):`. Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: Reading this should help https://stackoverflow.com/q/36921951/12846804 but first make sure quartiles.index(caracteristica) is a scalar? What is the datatype of that?

Comment: Also maybe you should pass quartiles as an argument to IQR

Comment: @AndrejKesely with that line I check if the argument wich I give to the function is the same as the index of the column in the list. If it is the same must calculate de IQR. So with this conditional I can get de IQR of a column I want without getting the IQR of the rest of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you can change your `IQR()` function to:

```py
def IQR(datos, columna):
    q = quartiles[columna - 1]
    return q[0.75] - q[0.25]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrejKeselev it works for all the columns. I also make it with the other function using numpy.